# Automate a webpage

Tags: vba, excel

I need to automate the webpage by using an Excel macro but I am getting a `Runtime Error 91` at the line `database2.Item(0).Value = mydatatype`.

Below is my code for that part:

```
objIE.document.getElementById("menu").Click
Set database2 = objIE.document.getElementsByname("select-prj")
database2.Item(0).Value = mydatatype
```

Below is the html source for that part:

```
<div class="item group-item">
    <div class="label-row">
        <span class="label">Database</span>
        <span id="menu" class="menu dropdown">
        </span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" id="select-prj" />
</div>
```

Please advise what I have done wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
objIE.document.getElementById("select-prj").Value = mydatatype
```

**Sample Code**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim objIE As Object

    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With objIE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "C:\Users\Siddharth\Desktop\test.htm"
        Do While .readystate <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
        .document.getElementById("select-prj").Value = "Sid"
    End With
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: But when i change database2.Item(0).Value = mydatatype to objIE.document.getElementsByname("select-prj").Value = mydatatype , it have an error '438'.

Comment: Can you share the exact weppage link?

Comment: Sorry...because this consist of some P&C, so i cann't share it out.

Comment: i found that the view source and inspect element in the webpage have different declaration, so i need to get the id from the view source not inspect element right?